# Mac VoiceOver does not announce aria-expanded state changes on Safari and FireFox (but it does on Chrome)

Tags: firefox, safari, accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover

Mac VoiceOver reads aria-expanded announced expanded and collapsed state change on Chrome but not on Safari and FireFox. On Safari and FireFox, it does properly read out 'Collapsed' or 'Expanded' when I tab onto it, but never when I toggle the state.

My HTML looks like:

```
<div role="group">
  <button aria-controls="id" type="button" href="#" aria-expanded="true">
    <div>Button</div>
  </button>
  <div id="id">
    <div role="list">
      <label role="listitem">
        <input>
        <span>text</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a click listener on the button to toggle the aria-expanded, which works as expected. With VoiceOver on Chrome, when I tab onto the button and `control+option+space` to toggle the button, VoiceOver announced the state each time it changes between Expanded and Collapsed. This is how I expect it to behave.

However, on Safari and FireFox, when I enter `control+option+space`, no state changes are announced by VoiceOver, even though I see the attribute changing in the button element in inspect tool.

While exploring other sites that use aria-expanded attribute, I came across [this one](https://www.naturevalley.com/). What I find interesting is that VoiceOver announces aria-expanded state changes for this site on both Chrome and Safari, but still not on FireFox. Makes me wonder if the issue isn't with my code, but browser compatibility with aria-expanded?

Comment: It seems to announce ok on iOS (Safari). I don't have the FF or Chrome app on iOS to test there. I also don't have a Mac to test, sorry. But wanted to give additional data points about where it works. Can you try the accordion example on https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/accordion/examples/accordion/ on the Mac?

Comment: One other thing to check. After you expand your button, are you moving the focus to the expanded content? That can sometimes cause VoiceOver to not announce things because it's busy announcing the new content. If you leave the focus on the element that just expanded, instead of moving it to the new content, then it *should* work.

Comment: @slugolicious

Focus remains on the button after collapse/expand via ctrl+option+space.

Thanks for sharing the accordion example; it behaves like the naturevalley site I linked (i.e., VoiceOver does not announce aria-expanded state changes on FireFox, but it does announce it on Chrome + Safari).

This leads me to think that the closest I can get is to fix my issue for Safari, and that Mac VoiceOver + FireFox + aria-expanded state change is an incompatible combination.

Comment: Possibly a bug with FF on the Mac. Perhaps check their bug database.